# why method get_entity returns 404

Tags: abap, sap-gateway

I have implemented the `get_entity` of the parent and it works for me but when I want to implement the `get_entity` of the child it doesn't work and I don't know why?

It gives me error

> 404

but what I want to consult is in the data table.

**This is the parent's `get_entity` method (it works)**:

```
  method ORGANIZADOREVENT_GET_ENTITY.
    CHECK line_exists( it_key_tab[ name = 'IdOrgevento' ] ).

    DATA(lv_id) = it_key_tab[ name = 'IdOrgevento' ]-value.

    SELECT SINGLE *
      FROM ZGAVAZ_ORGEVENTO
      WHERE ID_ORGEVENTO EQ @lv_id
      INTO CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF @er_entity.
  endmethod.
```

**This is the get_entity method of the child (it doesn't work, it gives me a 404 error)**

```
 method EVENTOSET_GET_ENTITY.
    CHECK line_exists( it_key_tab[ name = 'IdEvento' ] ).
    CHECK line_exists( it_key_tab[ name = 'IdOrgevento' ] ).

    DATA(lv_id) = it_key_tab[ name = 'IdEvento' ]-value.
    DATA(lv_id_eve) = it_key_tab[ name = 'IdOrgevento' ]-value.

    SELECT SINGLE *
      FROM ZGAVAZ_EVENTO
      WHERE ID_EVENTO EQ @lv_id  AND
            ID_ORGEVENTO EQ @lv_id_eve
      INTO CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF @er_entity.
  endmethod.
```

Table columns:

[image: SE11 table columns]

OData entity:

[image: x]

Table contents:

[image: SE16 table contents]

Comment: Did you try to set a debugger breakpoint to confirm that the method you wrote even gets executed?

Comment: And by the way, you misspelled the client field when you created your table. The standard convention is  `MANDT`, not `MADNT`. But that's probably not related to the problem.